# Zabbix remote command on windows

Tags: zabbix

I'm operating zabbix on windows servers.
I'm trying simple script execute via remote on zabbix,
So I modified target computer's zabbix_agentd.conf, EnableRemoteCommands 0 to 1.
And I ran successfully some windows command (like dir, run batch,tasklist) using zabbix_get command on zabbix server.
But the problem is what execute scripts on the Map is not functional.
The result is strange, and 2 patterns.

1.system.run['dir c:\dev\']

'system.run['dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

2.system.run[chcp 437 & dir] : referenced zabbix japan forum.

'system.run[chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 Volume in drive C is *********
 Volume Serial Number is *******

Directory of C:\Windows\system32

File Not Found

Result1 is cannot executed the 'dir' but Result2 is executed but failed result seems like permission denine.

What's wrong with me? :(

Comment: I reccomand you run the item from zabbix server cli, you can find info here on how to do it  using zabbix.get : https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/concepts/get    and also if its permission issue it could be that script can run with root user and not zabbix user  ? you have an option in conf to make zabbix run as root. try .

Comment: Thanks your comment. My description was bad, I tested zabbix_get and it returned result successfully. And system.run script was ran by administrator permission.

Comment: so with zabbix_get it works and with item it doesn't? are you sure windows agent conf has zabbix to run as admin? it should be there and also to allow remote command, check it out.